# Fixing misaligned Windows partition without affecting Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, grub, multi-boot

I have dual boot setup with my partitions set up like so:

- /dev/sda1 - DellUtility (FAT)
- /dev/sda2 - RECOVERY (NTFS)
- /dev/sda3 - OS (Windows 7 NTFS)
- /dev/sda4 - Extended

  - /dev/sda5 - swap
  - /dev/sda6 - ext4 (Ubuntu OS)
  - /dev/sda7 - ext4 (Ubuntu home)

I used Clonezilla to clone my hard drive and clearly screwed up something since now Ubuntu's Disk Utility reports that my partitions are misaligned. I can boot and use Ubuntu with no problems but Windows refuses to boot and shows a Windows Boot Manager error screen with status code 0xc000000e: [image: http://blogs.technet.com/blogfiles/deploymentguys/WindowsLiveWriter/Backtobasics2Brandingthedeployment_84EB/clip_image001_2.jpg]

I have a Windows installation disc but I'm worried that "Repairing my computer" could affect either grub or my Ubuntu partition. What's the best way to recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions on the error screen. That is, I inserted my OS disk then ran "Repair your computer". It worked like a charm. I can boot Windows and Ubuntu with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

### This is nothing to do with partition alignment.

Windows isn't complaining about misaligned partitions.  It's complaining that it cannot find the Windows boot loader, `winload`.  The reason that it cannot find it is that you've switched hard discs.  Microsoft's Boot Manager locates `winload`, and other so-called *boot applications,* by a combination of a hard disc ID, partition ID, and pathname within the partition.  It's looking for `winload` on a hard disc and partition combination that is no longer present on your system.

Presuming that your copy is otherwise — apart from the IDs — identical to the original: one workaround for this is, [as Alan Adams found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-GB/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/443251a3-46e6-4868-8f9d-5fdc5b838343/), to alter the BCD database entry for the Windows Boot Loader — which is where Microsoft's Boot Manager stores all of this information — to not use specific partition IDs but to use the generic "boot" identifier, using the `bcdedit` tool from the recovery command line:

```
BCDEDIT /set {bootmgr} device boot
BCDEDIT /set {default} device boot
BCDEDIT /set {default} osdevice boot
```

This sets the `device` and `osdevice` fields of the `{bootmgr}` (Microsoft's Boot Manager itself) and `{default}` (default selection — usually the Windows Boot Loader) entries in the database to "boot".  As M. Adams said, one will have to adjust `{memdiag}` and other entries if they exist and one wants to use them.  Multibooters has [a whole article on this](http://multibooters.co.uk./cloning.html).

Comment: Sorry, your answer made me realize I'm not having the "winload" issue. I've updated the image with a new one that matches what I'm actually seeing on my computer.